# Array to string conversion. Modificar datos de mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php5

Tengo el siguiente código que me genera una tabla en php devolviendome los datos guardados en una base de datos en mysql

```
require("conexion.php");

$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM clientes");

if (!$consulta) {
    die("Fallo al realizar la consulta");
}

echo ("<table border='1px'>");
echo ("<th> NOMBRE </th> <th> MEDIO DE PAGO </th> <th>PLAN CONTRATADO</th> <th> MODIFICAR </th> <th> ELIMINAR </th>");
while ($clientes = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
    echo ("<tr>");
    echo ("<td>$clientes[nombre]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$clientes[medioPago]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$clientes[plan]</td>");
    echo ("<td><a href='modificar.php?idC=$clientes[id]'>Modificar </a></td>");
    echo ("<td><a href='eliminar.php'>Eliminar </a></td>");
    echo ("</tr>");
}
echo ("</table>");
```

Como ven, cada registro me genera ademas un link que me lleva a la pagina modificar.php para modificar los datos en caso de que sea necesario. Con **idC=$clientes[id]** obtengo la ID del cliente que quiero modificar. En mi archivo *modificar.php* tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<form action="modificar.php">
        <label>Nuevo nombre: </label>
        <input type="text" name="nuevoNombre" placeholder="Ingrese el  nuevo nombre">

        <label>Medio de pago: </label>
        <select name="nuevoMedioPago">
            <option value="tarjeta">Tarjeta de credito</option>
            <option value="rapipago">Rapipago - Pagofacil</option>
            <option value="deposito">Deposito</option>
            <option value="efectivo">Efectivo</option>
            <option value="otro">Otro</option>
        </select>

        <label>Nuevo plan contratado: </label>
        <select name="nuevoPlanContratado">
            <option value="basico">Basico</option>
            <option value="avanzado">Avanzado</option>
            <option value="profesional">Profesional</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="Modificar">
    </form>


    <?php
    require("conexion.php");
    $idCliente = $_GET['idC'];

    echo ("Modificaras los datos del cliente cuya ID es: $idCliente <br>" );
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id = $idCliente");
    while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
        echo ("Nombre: $mostrar[nombre] <br>");
        echo ("Medio de pago: $mostrar[medioPago] <br>");
        echo ("Plan: $mostrar[plan] <br>");
    }

    ////////////////////////////ACTUALIZACION////////////////////////////
    $nuevoNombre = ['nuevoNombre'];
    $nuevoMedioPago = ['nuevoMedioPago'];
    $nuevoPlanContratado = ['nuevoPlanContratado'];

    $actualizar = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE clientes SET nombre='$nuevoNombre' , medioPago='$nuevoMedioPago' , plan='$nuevoPlanContratado' WHERE id = $idCliente");

    if (!$actualizar) {
        die("Fallo al actualizar los datos");
    }



    ?>
```

El cual me arroja error en la linea donde tengo mi consulta sql para actualizar los datos. 
En caso de que yo use GET o POST tanto en el formulario como a la hora de obtener el nuevo nombre, etc el error que me arroja es **Undefined index**.

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: `['nuevoNombre']` ? **Es incorrecto**  debería ser `$_POST['nuevoNombre']` , debe incluir como es que realizaste el proceso de añadir el _POST_

Comment: Como digo al final, en caso de hacerlo asi me dice Undefined index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`['nuevoNombre']` ? **Es incorrecto** debería ser `$_POST['nuevoNombre']` , si después de esto muestra el

> Undefined index.

Eso suele suceder porque al cargar la *modificar.php* ejecuta el código *PHP* y dentro de el , busca los indices que aún no han sido enviados por *POST* , ahí el detalle.

Para solucionar esto , podría verificar el tipo de petición si es *POST* haciendo uso de la clave `REQUEST_METHOD` de  `$_SERVER` para luego realizar las operaciones dependiendo del Tipo.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
   /* Aquí debería validar con isset las claves, por Ejemplo . si no puede 
    volver a tener problemas*/
    $idCliente = $_POST['idC'];
    $nuevoNombre = $_POST['nuevoNombre'];
    $nuevoMedioPago = $_POST['nuevoMedioPago'];
    $nuevoPlanContratado = $_POST['nuevoPlanContratado'];

    $actualizar = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE clientes SET nombre='$nuevoNombre' , medioPago='$nuevoMedioPago' , plan='$nuevoPlanContratado' WHERE id = $idCliente");

    if (!$actualizar) {
        die("Fallo al actualizar los datos");
    }
    else
       header("Location: nombredetuarchivo.php")
}
```

Bien , una solución al problema del `idCliente` sería el valor por *GET* directamente asignarlo a un *input*  *type* *hidden* para no perder el valor al hacer el *POST* , cambié el código *PHP* , para obtener el id por `POST` del campo *hidden*

```
  <form action="modificar.php" method="POST" >
  <input type="hidden" name="idC" value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['idC'])) ? $_GET['idC'] : 0 ?>">
```

Después de actualizar y verificar que se realizo la actualización en la bd *(else)* , podría redireccionar a la página que desee de la siguiente forma *(teniendo en cuenta la distribución de sus directorios)*

```
header("Location: nombredetuarchivo.php")
```

> Como recomendación leer [Evitar Inyección de código SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Bien, el problema es que no me actualiza los datos, por el contrario, al dar click en actualizar me lleva a un nuevo link creado automaticamente. Por ej http://localhost/Trabajo_Practico/modificar.php?nuevoNombre=Carlos&nuevoMedioPago=tarjeta&nuevoPlanContratado=basico

Comment: Probe poniendole el POST al form y me da error Array to string conversion y  Undefined variable: idCliente. Ambas en mi $actualizar

Comment: Actualice mi codigo a como actualmente dice tu respuesta y ahora solo me da el error de Undefined variable: idCliente

Comment: Perfecto! Me lo actualiza. El unico problema es que al actualizar me vuelve a cargar la pagina modificar.php. Hay forma de que luego de actualizar me lleve a otra pagina? Muchas gracias de verdad. Espero algun dia saber tanto como tu.

Comment: @LucasDavid sí , actualicé mi respuesta para esto.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo y predisposición!.